# Baggage Transfer from Incheon to Gimpo

Tags: luggage, airport-transfer, seoul, asiana-airlines

I arrive at Incheon on Asiana from London and then have a flight from Gimpo to Tokyo Haneda 3.5 hours later, also on Asiana.

Is this transfer time enough and will Asiana check my baggage all the way through to Tokyo Haneda, or will I have to collect it at Incheon and check it in again at Gimpo?

Answer (score 2):

You will indeed need to collect your bags yourself and transfer. Most airlines do not have a method of transferring between different airports in a city.

Indeed, [Asiana has this on their website](https://flyasiana.com/C/DE/EN/contents/transit-baggage).

They have a service if transferring to a domestic flight, even if at Gimpo, but (possibly due to regulations for international carriage), do not offer if transferring to another international flight.